When an aggregate inherits from an aggregate, is there risk of object slicing or memory leaks?
I am reading some material about C++17, I have a question about inheritance between aggregates.
If an aggregate inherits from an other aggregate, isn't it a problem ? Is there not any risk of slicing and memory leak ? I thought that when there were as inheritance, there should be virtual destructor.

"Is there not any risk of slicing and memory leak ?": I have no idea how you make the connection here. What slicing? What memory would leak? "I thought that when there were as inheritance, there should be virtual destructor.": That's wrong. A virtual destructor is required if the type is used polymorphic or even more specifically if an object of the derived class is destroyed through a pointer/reference of the base class type. Polymorphism with an aggregate class that doesn't have any class invariant doesn't really make sense though.

It's not the inheritance that causes the slicing.   It's what you do with an object once you create it.   For example, if B inherits from A, a function accepts an A by value (e.g. void func(A), an object is created of type B, and passed to that function (e.g. func(b)) then slicing will occur.      A virtual destructor is only essential to prevent undefined behaviour if instances of classes in the hierarchy are dynamically allocated and deallocated  e.g.  A *a = new B;  more_code(); delete a;, and not needed otherwise.

Slicing happens when you use something as a baseclass but it actually is a derived class. So in general it shouldn't be an issue unless you write incorrect code.


If an aggregate inherits from an other aggregate, isn't it a problem ?

No, not in itself. It all depends on how you use it.

Is there not any risk of slicing

I wouldn't see it as a risk. You can pass an object created from a derived class to a function accepting a reference to the base class and it can then operate on the base class members.

and memory leak ?

The object of the derived class will destroy its members when it goes out of scope, so not really.

I thought that when there were as inheritance, there should be virtual destructor.

Only if you aim to destroy an object of a derived class through a base class pointer do you really need a virtual destructor.

OK. So, that confirms what I thought: there is a risk, but it depends on the user. I used to never inherit from my aggregates, fearing a misuse. But maybe I'm wrong.
